# How can I get my own alert class respond to alertView clickedButtonAtIndex?

Tags: objective-c, class, optimization, uialertview

I have a class named AlertView because I use a lot of alerts in my app and I wanted to optimize the usage of my UIAlertViews.

But I have one problem when I want my AlertView class respond to the method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

This is how the UIAlertView looks in my AlertView.h

```
+ (void)simpleWithMessage:(NSString *)message withTag:(int)tag withOtherBtnTitle:(NSString *)otherBtnTitle;
```

This is how the UIAlertView looks in my AlertView.m

```
#pragma mark - Simple alert with tag

+ (void)simpleWithMessageAndTag:(NSString *)message withTag:(int)tag withOtherBtnTitle:(NSString *)otherBtnTitle
{
    UIAlertView *simpleWithMessageWithMessageAndTagAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm your choice!"
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:otherBtnTitle, nil];

    simpleWithMessageWithMessageAndTagAlertView.tag = tag;

    [simpleWithMessageWithMessageAndTagAlertView show];
}
```

And in a another class I import my AlertView.h and it works fine when I call it:

```
[AlertView simpleWithMessage:@"Do you want to delete?" withTag:901 withOtherBtnTitle:@"Yes"];
```

But the tag I use doesn't respond to my AlertView class method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Button actions for alert view with tag 901
    if (alertView.tag == 901) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            [self deleteMissionState];
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out what I'm missing here or if it's not possible to do what I want to do here.

Thanks in advance!

**EDITED**:

Found this tutorial which helped me explain what singleton is: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTfEN8KQPK8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your method `simpleWithMessageAndTag:withTag:WithOtherBtnTitle:` is a class method (declared with a `+` instead of `-`) and when you are assigning `self` as the delegate within that method, the *class* becomes the delegate, not an instance of the class.

Meanwhile the callback method `alerView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` is an instance method (`-` instead of `+`), so the class does not respond to that selector (an object of that class would). It will probably work if you change the `-` to `+` (despite it going against the text of the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol):

```
+ (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Or, better, change the `simpleWithMessageAndTag:withTag:WithOtherBtnTitle:` to an instance method and create an instance of the class (e.g., a singleton) on which you call that method, e.g.:

```
[[MyAlertViewFactory sharedFactory] simpleWithMessageAndTag:…];
// sharedFactory returns the same instance of MyAlertViewFactory every time
```

Comment: Thank you @Arkku, I solved it with you guidance and this example I found: http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/

I appreciate you took the time to help me in my quest for more optimized coding :)

Comment: shoul I use NSObject? I seem to get it to work but I discovered that my UIAlertView won't always respond. The UIAlerView won't run most of the time but if i restart the app it does, just to stop working again

Comment: @Oskariagon I'm guessing your singleton implementation is broken and only works one time or something like that. Set a breakpoint and see what goes on…

Comment: Yeah I'll check it out!